# Sending HTTPS GET request from android to python is not working

Tags: java, android, json, https, getjson

I'm trying to establish a https connection between an android app (client) an my laptop (server). 
My https server is running as python script (with a letsencrypt certificate) which works fine as long as I try to connect it with chrome or another python script.

Now I wanted to implement the client in my android app. Therefore I added the permission to the `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

and added following lines to my `MainActivity.java` (based on [HttpURLConnection Reference on Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html)!:

```
public void onButtonClicked(String message) {

    try {
        URL url = new URL("https://foo.bar.com/");
        HttpsURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        OutputStream output = new BufferedOutputStream(urlConnection.getOutputStream());

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    mSecondFragment.updateMessage(message);

}
```

At the moment I just want to establish a connection to my https server and send a simple GET request without receiving any data. But my goal would be to parse an additional key value pair together with the `GET` request that will be processed by the server:

```
"https://foo.bar.com?a=1"
```

I tried to keep it as simple as possible (that's the reason why I wanted to use `java.net.HttpURLConnection`) but I assume the problem is not as trivial as I expected.

Maybe someone ran into the same problem and can help my with that :)

EDIT (Thanks to @atomicrat2552 and @petey):

I added an additional class that handles the request as an AsyncTask:

```
public class NetworkConnection extends AsyncTask<String, Void, NetworkConnection.Result> {

    static class Result {
        public String mResultValue;
        public Exception mException;
        public Result(String resultValue) {
            mResultValue = resultValue;
        }
        public Result(Exception exception){
            mException = exception;
        }
    }

    protected NetworkConnection.Result doInBackground(String... urls) {
        Result result = null;
        HttpsURLConnection urlConnection = null;

        try {
            URL url = new URL(urls[0]);
            urlConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            //urlConnection.connect();
            result = new Result("Done");
        }catch(Exception e) {
            result = new Result(e);
        } finally {
            if (urlConnection != null) {
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

This leads to a simplified onButtonClick method in `MainActivity.java`:

```
NetworkConnection nwConn = new NetworkConnection();

public void onButtonClicked(String message) {

    nwConn.execute("https://foo.bar.com");
    mSecondFragment.updateMessage(message);

}
```

Again I tried to simplify the code in order to get a small working code a can extend later.
The app doesn't crash anymore but my server still doesn't show any requests. If I'm using the browser on my phone everything works just fine. Any idea?

Comment: Are you getting an exception? Logcat?

Comment: Are you just forgetting to call [urlConnection.connect()](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLConnection.html#connect())?

Comment: No, there is no need for connect, he is getting NOMTException. *Maybe someone ran into the same problem* Yeah, bazillion people, search for your exception

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/how-to-fix-android-os-networkonmainthreadexception)

Answer (score 0):

The most common pitfall I see here is that network code cannot run on the UI thread, so you must use some sort of background worker to do your network calls. The developer site has [a basic guide](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html) on how to do this.

Comment: Thanks! I added parts of the code I assume are necessary to run a basic GET request. (I compared the code @petey was mentioning). The app is now running smoothly but my server still gets no requests. If I'm using the browser on my phone everything seems fine. I will edit my initial question and add the resulting code.